# Python findall using xpath pattern with logical AND

Tags: python, xpath, findall

Here is my xpath:

```
<Unit>
  <_unit_type>FSP</_unit_type>
  <_logicalId>FSM1/FSP1</_logicalId>
</Unit>
<Unit>
  <_unit_type>FSP</_unit_type>
  <_logicalId>FSM1/FSP2</_logicalId>
</Unit>
```

So I need to find `len(root.findall(xpath_pattern)` when my `xpath_pattern = .//Unit[_unitType='FSP'][starts-with(_logicalId,'FSM1']`

If my pattern is `.//Unit[_unitType='FSP']`, my code works and I can get the length which is 2. But I need to add another qualifier since my xml file is much more complicated.

Im getting SyntaxError: invalid predicate when using this pattern 
`.//Unit[_unitType='FSP'][starts-with(_logicalId,'FSM1']`

Comment: Which python module are you importing? Except fot [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/), I don't know any that supports full XPath standard.

Comment: Im using lxml in parsing my xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use AND operators to add the conditions you need.

Example if you're looking for a specific "Unit":

```
//Unit[_unit_type='FSP' and contains(.,'S')][starts-with(_logicalid,'FSM1') AND contains(.,'FSP1')]
```

You can also use "|" to operate with multiple XPaths. Xpath1|Xpath2|Xpath3|...
If you are looking for something different than Unit :

```
//Unit[_unit_type='FSP'][starts-with(_logicalid,'FSM1')]|//Entity[_unit_type='XYZ'][starts-with(_logicalid,'FSM1')]
```

Comment: I've all possible AND operators, even the one you posted but I still get the Invalid Predicate syntax error. :(

Comment: What happens if you remove underscore from your unit_type and logicalid tags in your html code (underscore is not allowed in tags) ? Of course, do the same for the XPath.

Comment: Also, XPath is case sensitive: logical conjunction operator is `and`.

Answer (score 1):

You have written

```
.//Unit[_unitType='FSP'][starts-with(_logicalId,'FSM1']
```

and this causes an Invalid Predicate syntax error. It is becaue of the missing closing parenthesis. Try this:

```
.//Unit[_unitType='FSP'][starts-with(_logicalId,'FSM1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `lxml` module keeps for compatibility reasons two different XPath engines. From [lxml FAQ](https://lxml.de/3.0/FAQ.html#what-are-the-findall-and-xpath-methods-on-element-tree):

> `findall()` is part of the original **ElementTree API**. It supports a
> **simple subset of the XPath language**, without predicates, conditions and other advanced features. [...]
>
> `xpath()`, on the other hand, supports the complete power of the XPath language, including predicates, XPath functions and Python extension functions.

Use `xpath()` method like in

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML("""
<root> 
  <Unit> 
    <_unit_type>FSP</_unit_type>  
    <_logicalId>FSM1/FSP1</_logicalId> 
  </Unit>  
  <Unit> 
    <_unit_type>FSP</_unit_type>  
    <_logicalId>FSM1/FSP2</_logicalId> 
  </Unit> 
</root>""")
print(root.xpath(".//Unit[_unit_type='FSP'][starts-with(_logicalId,'FSM1')]"))
```

Console output:

```
[<Element Unit at 0x7fa1e0413140>, <Element Unit at 0x7fa1e04130f0>]
```

Check in [here](https://repl.it/repls/PartialScrawnyRecords)